# javascript executing then undoing

Tags: javascript

I have an aspx page where I'm trying to hide a div based on a button click. It seems as though the javascript executes but then the div shows back up immediately. It seems like the page is refreshing as well.

```
function hideDiv2()
    {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";

    }
```

This is the html

```
<body>
<form id="form1">
<div style="background-color:gray;">

    <div id="div1" style="width:300px; background-color:blue;">
        <button onclick="hideDiv2()"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" runat="server" style="width:300px; background-color:black; display:none;">test</div>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the button submitting the form?

Comment: Is the button in a `<form>` element?

Comment: The current code here will not reproduce behaviour stated.

Comment: yes it is in a <form> element

Comment: Http is stateless. That is if you repost the page, of course it will load back up as if it were the first time the page loaded. It doesn't (naturally) remember anything from previous pages.

Comment: So change the button code to `<button type="button" ...>`, so it won't submit the form by default.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the the problem was that the button was inside a form which was resubmitting the page each time. The solution was to change the type="button"